# activemq constantly retrying error messages and not picking up new messages

Tags: queue, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have an activemq instance set up with tomcat for background message processing. It is set up to retry failed messages every 10 minutes for a retry period.

Now some dirty data has entered the system because of which the messages are failing. This is ok and can be fixed in the future. However, the problem is that none of the new correct incoming messages are getting processed and the error messages are constantly getting retried.

Any tips on what might be the issue, or how the priority is set? I haven't controlled the priority of the messages manually.

Thanks for your help.

-Pulkit

EDIT : I was able to solve the problem. The issue was that by the time all the dirty messages were handled, it was time for them to be retried. Thus none of the new messages were being consumed by the queue.
A dirty message was basically a message that was throwing an exception out due to some dirty data in the system. the redelivery settings was to do redeliveries every 10 mins for 1 day.
    maximumRedeliveries=144
    redeliveryDelayInMillis=600000
    acknowledge.mode=transacted

Comment: Can you add some detail about how you set up retries, and how you define/handle a failed message? There isn't enough information in the question above.

Comment: I think that "poison message" it is the proper terminology accepted by the community

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ determines redelivery for a consumer based on the configuration of the RedeliveryPolicy that's assigned the ActiveMQConnectionFactory.  Local redelivery halts new message dispatch until the rollbed back transaction messages are successfully redelivered so if you have a message that's causing you some sort of error such that you are throwing an exception or rolling back the transaction then it will get redelivered up to the max re-deliveries setting in the policy.  Since your question doesn't provide much information on your setup and what you consider an error message I can't really direct you to a solution.

You should look at the settings available in the Redelivery Policy.  Also you can configure redelivery to not block new message dispatch using the setNonBlockingRedelivery method.